# Error running LUKS reencryption without formatting

Tags: luks, dm-crypt

I am unable to run luks reencryption. I have data on `/dev/sdc1` and would like to encrypt it without the need to format. I am trying to utilize the luks2 online encryption feature.

```
mathew@plug:/mnt $ sudo cryptsetup reencrypt --new --reduce-device-size 16M /dev/sdc1
Usage: cryptsetup [-?vyrq] [-?|--help] [--usage] [--version] [-v|--verbose] [--debug] [--debug-json] [-c|--cipher=STRING] [-h|--hash=STRING]
        [-y|--verify-passphrase] [-d|--key-file=STRING] [--master-key-file=STRING] [--dump-master-key] [-s|--key-size=BITS]
        [-l|--keyfile-size=bytes] [--keyfile-offset=bytes] [--new-keyfile-size=bytes] [--new-keyfile-offset=bytes] [-S|--key-slot=INT]
        [-b|--size=SECTORS] [-o|--offset=SECTORS] [-p|--skip=SECTORS] [-r|--readonly] [-q|--batch-mode] [-t|--timeout=secs]
        [--progress-frequency=secs] [-T|--tries=INT] [--align-payload=SECTORS] [--header-backup-file=STRING] [--use-random] [--use-urandom]
        [--shared] [--uuid=STRING] [--allow-discards] [--header=STRING] [--test-passphrase] [--tcrypt-hidden] [--tcrypt-system]
        [--tcrypt-backup] [--veracrypt] [--veracrypt-pim=INT] [--veracrypt-query-pim] [-M|--type=STRING] [--force-password]
        [--perf-same_cpu_crypt] [--perf-submit_from_crypt_cpus] [--deferred] [-i|--iter-time=msecs] [--pbkdf=STRING] [--pbkdf-memory=kilobytes]
        [--pbkdf-parallel=threads] [--pbkdf-force-iterations=LONG] [--priority=STRING] [--disable-locks] [--disable-keyring]
        [-I|--integrity=STRING] [--integrity-no-journal] [--integrity-no-wipe] [--token-only] [--token-id=INT] [--key-description=STRING]
        [--sector-size=INT] [--persistent] [--label=STRING] [--subsystem=STRING] [--unbound] [--json-file=STRING] [--luks2-metadata-size=bytes]
        [--luks2-keyslots-size=bytes] [--refresh] [--keyslot-key-size=BITS] [--keyslot-cipher=STRING] [OPTION...] <action> <action-specific>
--new: unknown option
```

As specified in this document - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Cryptsetup_usage I also tried, but still get error:

```
mathew@plug:/mnt $ sudo cryptsetup reencrypt --encrypt --reduce-device-size 16M /dev/sdc1
Usage: cryptsetup [-?vyrq] [-?|--help] [--usage] [--version] [-v|--verbose] [--debug] [--debug-json] [-c|--cipher=STRING] [-h|--hash=STRING]
        [-y|--verify-passphrase] [-d|--key-file=STRING] [--master-key-file=STRING] [--dump-master-key] [-s|--key-size=BITS]
        [-l|--keyfile-size=bytes] [--keyfile-offset=bytes] [--new-keyfile-size=bytes] [--new-keyfile-offset=bytes] [-S|--key-slot=INT]
        [-b|--size=SECTORS] [-o|--offset=SECTORS] [-p|--skip=SECTORS] [-r|--readonly] [-q|--batch-mode] [-t|--timeout=secs]
        [--progress-frequency=secs] [-T|--tries=INT] [--align-payload=SECTORS] [--header-backup-file=STRING] [--use-random] [--use-urandom]
        [--shared] [--uuid=STRING] [--allow-discards] [--header=STRING] [--test-passphrase] [--tcrypt-hidden] [--tcrypt-system]
        [--tcrypt-backup] [--veracrypt] [--veracrypt-pim=INT] [--veracrypt-query-pim] [-M|--type=STRING] [--force-password]
        [--perf-same_cpu_crypt] [--perf-submit_from_crypt_cpus] [--deferred] [-i|--iter-time=msecs] [--pbkdf=STRING] [--pbkdf-memory=kilobytes]
        [--pbkdf-parallel=threads] [--pbkdf-force-iterations=LONG] [--priority=STRING] [--disable-locks] [--disable-keyring]
        [-I|--integrity=STRING] [--integrity-no-journal] [--integrity-no-wipe] [--token-only] [--token-id=INT] [--key-description=STRING]
        [--sector-size=INT] [--persistent] [--label=STRING] [--subsystem=STRING] [--unbound] [--json-file=STRING] [--luks2-metadata-size=bytes]
        [--luks2-keyslots-size=bytes] [--refresh] [--keyslot-key-size=BITS] [--keyslot-cipher=STRING] [OPTION...] <action> <action-specific>
--encrypt: unknown option
```

I referred to the manpage here - https://man.cx/cryptsetup(8) and as per them my above command should have worked!

My `cryptsetup` version is 2.1.0 and I don't see any upgrade when trying `apt-get install` or `apt-get upgrade`.

I am confused and stuck :(

Comment: Neither source mentions an option `--new`... Have you reduced the file system accordingly? You should put all options between `cryptsetup` and `reencrypt`.

Comment: I tried placing options b/w ```cryptsetup``` and ```reencrypt```. Didn't work. I am fairly sure this is a version problem. My distro is Raspbain 10 and it looks like their version is outdated. I am trying to figure out a way to update the ```cryptsetup``` version.

Answer (score 1):

I finally compiled from source and it worked.

Comment: And which version did you compile from source?

Comment: Downloaded the latest from gitlab (2.3.2)

Comment: Then may I suggest that you edit your answer to include that information, and possibly anything you had to do to install it that wasn't readily obvious from the documentation provided. That way, others facing a similar proble can profit from your experience; also otherwise your post might get "delete" votes by moderators for being a comment rather than an actual answer.